# Firestore negative impacts for orphan subcollections

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The firestore docs say:

> When you delete a document that has associated subcollections, the subcollections are not deleted. They are still accessible by reference. For example, there may be a document referenced by `db.collection('coll').doc('doc').collection('subcoll').doc('subdoc')` even though the document referenced by `db.collection('coll').doc('doc')` no longer exists.

Since deleting collections is not recommended from a web client, it seems the easiest thing to do in that case would be to delete the document and leave the orphaned subcollection.

Are there any negative impacts to leaving lots of orphaned subcollections in your database?

Comment: I think there is no negative impacts. unless the firebase has own limits for each service. So, database usage limits at Firestore is: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas

Comment: These orphaned subcollections will lead you to exceed your 1 Gib Stored data quota faster.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are negative impacts of leaving orphaned collections in your database.

First, that is space you've already wasted. You'll just end up exceeding your quotas or budgets faster.

Secondly, bad queries - you can end up with a query, lets say, you want to filter all documents by a condition on a property of documents in different sub collections. That would include your orphaned sub collections too. This is inefficient both performance-wise and cost-wise.

Moreover, I am not even sure how that would impact any index you want to create. In general, leaving orphaned entries in a nested document database is a bad idea, especially if it is not at the leaf level of your structure.

Easiest thing to do - Create a cloud function that cleans up all your orphaned sub collections. You can always call that from the client in turn.